# npm ERR while installing ionic

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I am on Windows 10 trying to install Ionic. I ran the following code in the terminal:

```
npm install -g @ionic/CLI
```

And I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Lari\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic.ps1
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Users\Lari\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic.ps1: is outside C:\Users\Lari\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\Lari\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic.ps1
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Lari\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-12T22_24_22_577Z-debug.log
```

I have ran the following commands to debug:

- `npm uninstall -g ionic`
- `npm install -g @ionic/cli`
- `npm install -g cordova @ionic/cli`

and much more for over a week now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied and paste this path in windows

C:\Users\Lari\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic

Deleted all ionic folders, and then this path

C:\Users\Lari\AppData\Roaming\npm

Deleted some ionic files present as well.

Ran npm I -g @ionic/cli and it did install version 6.11.0.
Thanks everyone, hope it helps someone